# How can I improve the chance of Solar Eclipse happening in Terraria

Tags: terraria

Is any way to improve the chances of a solar eclipse happening (apart from killing the mechanical bosses). 
Basically I want to get broken hero swords to be able to forge the terra blade...

Answer (score 9):

Based on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/226858/104124), you can summon a solar eclipse with the Solar tablet at any point in daytime since v1.3 (on PC version).

A solar tablet can be crafted from 8 solar fragments on a hardmode anvil.

Solar fragments can be looted from the lizahrd temple mobs & chests, and you can even find a full tablet in a chest.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to improve the chance to get a solar eclipse.
The 1 in 25 chance is fixed and can't be changed. You just need to be lucky.

Answer (score 8):

Download TEdit click Open then select your world  then click is solar eclipse and press save wait for it to load and done.

Comment: While this is one method to go about it, I feel this is not actually a legitimate way to do this.

Comment: @Frank: Well, the other option is waiting mindlessly for a solar eclipse to happen. So you're basically only speeding up time by doing this (properly). Illegitimate in my eyes would be to just give yourself the broken swords.

Comment: Normally I'm not okay with cheating or save editing, but IMO I think it's justified in this case. RNG is a bunch of BS, and I wish developers would stop forcing their players to get lucky before they can progress. Same goes for the key molds.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to actually speed up solar eclipse as well as blood moon in the game

Answer (score -1):

I suggest just stay in Terraria for 25 Terraria days since its a 1 in 25 chance that means the odds of you getting a solar eclipse in at least 1 of those days is like REALLY HIGH it's like an 100% chance

Comment: that's not how it works. when you flip a coin you have a 1 in 2 chances it'll be heads. by your logic there's a 100% chance you will get heads at least once in 2 tosses which is totally wrong as if you record each toss you can find times where you wont get heads for several tosses

Comment: 64% actually. That's sorta like 100% if you don't think about it too hard.

Comment: This is a classic example of the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). *Each day* has a 1/25 chance of a solar eclipse... has nothing to do with how many days you've already waited. it's quite possible (I'd even argue pretty common) that you can go for 25 in-game days without seeing an eclipse.