# How do you farm the solar eclipse? If you can, what is the design?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I have been trying to get broken hero swords for the terra blade.

Comment: Keep in mind, the solar eclipse is getting a massive overhaul come end of June, so any strategies outlined here may no longer be valid at end of June.

Comment: Why? I don't get it.

Comment: Because the addition of new enemies may render old tactics invalid.

Comment: Ok now I get it so it's a invalid tactic? Darn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a screenshot of my solar "farm" from my [Steam Screenshots](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=459551771):

[image: Solar Farm]

It is not AFK, but it is a lot of waiting mostly.  The mother slimes sometimes break into slime-lings through the wall and can get annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Now that 1.3 is here, you can trigger the Solar Eclipse at will, like most other events.

After you have gotten access to the temple inside the jungle, you can farm solar shards to create solar tables. Use eight shards on a Mythril/Orichalcum anvil to craft a tablet; the shards drop randomly from the temple enemies.

You can use the Tablet on daytime to trigger a Solar Eclipse. That should let you farm the event much more frequently.

Answer (score -3):

You should simply farm the Lizard temple until you get 8 Solar Shards.